# strcpy in C does not copy properly to overwrite a string

Tags: c, string, strcpy

I am trying to implement a infix to postfix conversion program in C. I wrote (cleanExpression) the following function to remove unwanted space in the given infix string expression.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <string.h>

#define EXPR_LIMIT 1000

bool isNumber(char c) {
    return (c >= '0' && c <= '9');
};

bool cleanInfixExpression(char *expr, char **clean) {
    *clean = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(expr) + 1);
    strcpy(*clean, expr);
    char *curr = *clean;
    char *temp;
    char *temp_dest;
    // first count the number of terms (numbers and operators).
    while (*curr != 0) {
        // check if the current position is space.
        if (*curr == ' ') {
            printf("Current:%s\n", curr);
            printf("Clean  :%s\n\n", *clean);

            // go through all space positions.
            for(temp = curr; *temp == ' '; temp++) {};

            // make its numbers on both side of the space.
            if (curr != *clean && (isNumber(*(curr-1)) && (isNumber(*temp)))) {
                printf("\"%s\" : Invalid expression!\n", expr);
                free(*clean);
                return (false);
            }

            // copy into the the original string.
            strcpy(curr, temp);
        }
        curr++;
    }
    printf("Current:%s\n", curr);
    printf("Clean  :%s\n\n", *clean);
    return (true);
};


void main(void) {
    char expr[EXPR_LIMIT] = " 214      +              9523        - 235235";
    printf("INFIX expression: %s\n", expr);
    char *clean;
    if (cleanInfixExpression(expr, &clean)) {
        printf("%s\n", clean);
    }
    return;
}
```

When I run this code the following is the output I get.

```
INFIX expression:  214      +            9523        - 235235
Current: 214      +            9523        - 235235
Clean  : 214      +            9523        - 235235

Current:      +            9523        - 235235
Clean  :214      +            9523        - 235235

Current:      952   9523        - 235235
Clean  :214+      952   9523        - 235235

Current:   9523        - 235235
Clean  :214+952   9523        - 235235

" 214      +            9523        - 235235" : Invalid expression!
```

However, if I change the strcpy(curr, temp) to the following code, where I manually copy, then I get the correct output.

```
temp_dest = curr;
while(*temp != 0) {
    *(temp_dest++) = *(temp++);
}
*temp_dest = 0;
```

This the output with me manually copying the string, instead of using the strcpy function.

```
INFIX expression:  214      +              9523        - 235235
Current: 214      +              9523        - 235235
Clean  : 214      +              9523        - 235235

Current:      +              9523        - 235235
Clean  :214      +              9523        - 235235

Current:              9523        - 235235
Clean  :214+              9523        - 235235

Current:        - 235235
Clean  :214+9523        - 235235

Current: 235235
Clean  :214+9523- 235235

Current:
Clean  :214+9523-235235

214+9523-235235
```

I am not able to understand what mistake I am making in using strcpy. Can someone tell me what might be going on?

Comment: I think the issue surrounds the fact you're using `strcpy(dst, src)` where `dst` and `src` are overlapping strings. The manual page for `strcpy` says that the strings may not overlap. The algorithm inside `strcpy` doesn't necessarily match the manual version you have. In addition, your manual copy changes `temp` but `strcpy(curr, temp)` does not. It's not clear what your context is for the manual version, but if you just put it directly in place of your `strcpy(curr, temp)` call, it's not doing the same thing.

Comment: You should `malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(expr) + 1))` i.e. *strlen(expr) + 1 chars*, not *strlen(expr) chars + 1 byte*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to use `malloc` for `cleanInfixExpression` just to remove the spaces:

Do this

```
void cleanInfixExpression(char *expr)
{
   int r = 0;
   int w = 0;
   for (; expr[r]; r++) {
      if (expr[r] != ' ') {
         expr[w] = expr[r];
         ++w;
      }
   }
   expr[w] = 0;
 }
```

It will remove unwanted spaces from expr

Answer (score 1):

From the standard:

> **7.21.2.3 The strcpy function**
>   **Description**
>   2 The strcpy function copies the string pointed to by s2 (including the terminating null
>   character) into the array pointed to by s1. ***If copying takes place between objects that
>   overlap, the behavior is undefined***.

So you are not allowed to `strcpy` overlapping strings - as you do. You need to write your own implementation of `strcpy` or use `memmove`.